# basic python repeated printing advice required

Tags: python

I'm making a grid of 0's and I want my row to print on a new line but I want a simpler way then constantly asking print(row). This is my code so far.

```
row = []

for i in range(0,1):

    row.append(" O " * 5)
    print(row)
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a grid of fixed strings you don't need *any* loops, you can just use string and list multiplication, and the string `.join` method to join the rows of the grid together for printing.

```
size = 5
row = " O " * size
grid = [row] * size
print('\n'.join(grid))
```

**output**

```
 O  O  O  O  O 
 O  O  O  O  O 
 O  O  O  O  O 
 O  O  O  O  O 
 O  O  O  O  O
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is iterating through a two-dimensional list of zeros.

```
# The dimensions of the two-dimensional list.
columns = 5
rows    = 5

# A generator to produce the two-dimensional list.
zeros = [[0 for i in range(columns)] for j in range(rows)]

# Loops through and prints each row of the two-dimensional list.
for row in zeros:

    print(row)
```

For the given dimensions, the output when this code is executed is as follows:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you i actually took 0TTT0 advice and wrote another looprow = []
grid = 5

for i in range(0,1):
    row.append(" O " * 5)
    #print(row)
    while grid> 0:
        print(row)
        grid = grid - 1

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = [[0 for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
[print(row) for row in grid]
```

Outputs:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Your first line of code is fine, but the second line isn't so good. Please don't use list comprehensions like that! Just use a "traditional" `for` loop. Your `[print(row) for row in grid]` creates a list full of `None`, and then throws that list away. It's generally considered bad style for a list comp to have any side effects at all: it shouldn't have any other effect apart from building the list. So using a list comp _purely_ for the side effects and throwing the list away is a big no-no.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!